# Is there such a thing as a “corrosion break”?

Tags: battery-operated, circuit-protection

More often than not, battery powered electronics will result in a battery that leaks, which if not caught, can corrode the whole circuit.

I recently bought a used piece of electronics with battery terminals soldered to a PCB. The corrosion was so bad it corroded the PCB and several electrical components soldered to it.

This got me thinking - we have sacrificial fuses to protect circuits from too much current. Is there something equivalent that can act as a sacrificial corrosion break? If batteries leak, corrosion will stop at the break without damaging the rest of the circuit?

Comment: You would need a physical barrier or gap that the fluids leaking from the battery can't cross.

Comment: Further, it should be obvious that no manufacturer of such devices has any economic motivation whatsoever to include such a feature.

Comment: As Dave says, the motivation is opposite. Think about the “indicators” in portable electronics which do not cut off internal batteries to prevent water damage, but rather create evidence that allows the manufacturer to easily void warranty coverage.

Comment: Automotive lead-acid battery terminals are coated with a paste of grease and an alkali, such as MgOH, to neutralize leaking sulfuric acid.